# Deriving new column using new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, column-alias

Normally we can build new columns in Select statements. Is it possible to derive new columns out of new columns in Select statements?

For example,

```
Select 1+2 A
```

This gives us a table with column A and the value 3 in 1 row.

Can I build a new column B that is based on A?

For example,

```
Select 1+2 A, 4+A B
```

Unfortunately the above will result in "Invalid column name A".

Comment: You can't. You can wrap query 1 up in a derived table, and then add the B column.

Comment: so does it mean that for every additional new derived column, I have to build a derived table first?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: My base table has a large number of records (10 million) and the requirement is to add 5 new columns which are derived from previously derived columns. I originally intend to build a view with a single create statement such that all new columns can be declared together.

Comment: You don't need multiple create statements because the outer query and the subquery are part of your select statement

Comment: Wouldn't it become a performance issue when i wrap queries within queries on large tables?

Comment: @VictorNg . . . Generally no performance issue but you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery.

```
select 4 + A as 'B'
from (
    select 1 + 2 as 'A'
) q
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary table

```
Select 1+2 as A
INTO #TEMPORARY_TABLE
FROM TABLE

SELECT 4+A as B
FROM #TEMPORARY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to wrap it up in 5 different subqueries / derived tables / CTEs.

Just write the full logic for each derived columns.

```sql
select 2-1 as A, 4+ (2-1) as B, 5* (4+(2-1)) as C
```